# English. I am doing a report and need your help

Tags: word-choice

yes I have a very important question. Does the English language have and academy like the Royal Spanish Academy? Anyone who answers is so very kind.Word-choice?

Comment: No.  The nearest equivalent are high quality dictionaries, but these aim to  be descriptive rather than prescriptive

Comment: Some people here seem to believe that CGEL is such.

Answer (score -1):

The **British National Corpus (BNC)** was originally created by Oxford University press in the 1980s - early 1990s, and it contains 100 million words of text texts from a wide range of genres (e.g. spoken, fiction, magazines, newspapers, and academic).

The **Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)** is the largest freely-available corpus of English, and the only large and balanced corpus of American English. COCA is probably the most widely-used corpus of English, and it is related to many other corpora of English that we have created, which offer unparalleled insight into variation in English.

The corpus contains more than 520 million words of text (20 million words each year 1990-2015) and it is equally divided among spoken, fiction, popular magazines, newspapers, and academic texts.